# C# Converting a string to date/datetime for sort option in DataTable.Select statement

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable

I have a C# program that reads data from a CSV file into a DataTable.  This means that all the columns in the resultant DataTable are strings.  I then need to Select from the DataTable a subset of rows that match the criteria of a shared value within a single column.  This works fine.

My problem comes in that I also need the return set sorted by another column which is a date.  I cannot figure out how to format that sort parameter in the Select function to convert the string expression of the date to a real date so the sort works properly.

Can this be done with the Select statement or do I need to take another approach?

Comment: If datetime is in iso format you can sort it as string. Otherwise use `DateTime.ParseExact(string, format)`

Comment: Stan, your suggestion is not working.  I end up with a code snippet like; 
dtDataTable.Select("IDColumn = '222'", DateTime.ParseExact(DateColumn, "d/M/yyyy");

This throws an error Cannot find column DateTime.ParseExact(DateColumn,.

Answer (score 0):

You can load file using schema.ini https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx and define type for your columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is one thing you can try. This will iterate over each row in the DataTable and get the String of the date from the column that you specify. It will turn the String into a DateTime using TryParse. If this succeeds, Row[0] will be set to the DateTime. If it fails, row[0] will not be changed.

I have set the column to 0 in the below code, but you should change all 0's to whatever column the DateTime is in.

```
DateTime dateValue;
foreach(DataRow row in dtDataTable.Rows){            
  if(DateTime.TryParse(row[0], out dateValue)){
    row[0] = dateValue        
  }
}
```

You can find more info on TryParse [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx). TryParse can have unpredictable behavior, so for even more control I would recommend upgrading to [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) once you get this working.